# Why doesn't PHP report this error?

Tags: php, error-reporting

Server is running PHP5.3. I found the problem by commenting out code until the page run. When I first loaded the page I got no output with no errors.

I set error reporting to:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Note: Notices need to be disabled because the system is old and was originally poorly written (something we are resolving now bit by bit)

The line which stopped the script running without errors was this one.

```
<?php echo explode('cms/', pageURL())[0]?>
```

This works fine in PHP5.4. It is fine that 5.3 doesn't support this but why doesn't an error display? What is it about this precisely which makes it so difficult to debug? This has happened once or twice for various problems and it would be good to have a better understanding of the underlying issue.

Is it possible to get errors to show on 5.3 with this problem?

Error reporting is working on the server.

```
poop();
```

Returns

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function poop()`

EDIT: While updating the code a failed at editing and had a line which contained this:

```
$parts = echo explode('cms/',pageURL());
```

This caused the same problem. No output, no errors. The script just fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background info:

If your `error_reporting` settings are being setup via function call (not settings files), a *syntax error* which occurs in the first file being loaded (ex.: `index.php`) the PHP interpreter can't output the error.

If you have a very simple `index.php` file which includes the file with the fatal syntax error in it, then the PHP interpreter will be able to output the error.

This is a "known limitation" of the PHP interpreter caused by the fact that most interpreters need to read the file in *two passes* first to pick up the tokens and then to assess if the tokens correctly represent the language's grammar (allowed order of tokens).

Actually *running* the code happens after the interpreter finishes these *two passes* successfully; if it doesn't then all the information the interpreter has is that a syntax error occurred, it doesn't know that you have set `error_reporting` to some level or another because it considers whatever it read from the file to be "invalid syntax" so it can't run it.

### Concrete info:

Since you're using a new *syntactic* language construct that PHP 5.4 provides but PHP 5.3 doesn't, the legitimate PHP 5.4 construct becomes a *syntax error* in PHP 5.3.

Having a call to `error_reporting` in the same file as the syntax error means the function call will not occur and the error level will not be correctly set.

### Workaround:

Set your error level by declaring it in your `php.ini` file or `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2):

### Parse errors occur before parsing the file

With the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo explode('cms/', pageURL())[0]
```

The code needs to be *parsed* before the contents are processed. Running with display errors on by default you'd see:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in index.php on line 4

Or similar. If there is a parse error - none of the file is parsed at all, the error is processed before any of the file's contents (which are never processed, as it's a fatal error), and therefore the error reporting settings from *before* the file was loaded are what applies.

By contrast, this would show the error message:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require 'has_fatal_error.php';

<?php
// has_fatal_error.php;
echo explode('cms/', pageURL())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but it's possible that this particular type of error falls under `E_STRICT`.  In PHP 5.4, `E_STRICT` is included in `E_ALL`, but in 5.3 it was not.

Regardless of whether or not this fixes it, it would be prudent to change your error reporting to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Error levels for logging & displaying in this situation would not help. But I get where you're coming from. I use `E_ALL` by default.

Comment: Yeah, after a couple other answers here (including yours), it's pretty clear that his error levels aren't the problem.  Nonetheless, I do still think it's prudent to include `E_STRICT` anyway, so I decided to leave it for him.

Answer (score 0):

If the first file loaded by apache contains parse error, the code is never run.

Answer (score -3):

You need to set in ini file `short_open_tag = On` after that you will recive the error

Comment: There shuld be a problem of php tag

Comment: open your php.ini file from wamp and search short_open_tag and replace the value off to on

Comment: He's not using a short open tag, so why would that help?

Comment: No, why is there a problem with the open/close tags? There is a problem earlier in the code, but the close tag is correct.

Comment: in that page there should be some code <? ?> for php then it will not work right now in the question they defined only the 2 lines code

Comment: @Nikul it's not an unreasonable guess - but it's by far not the most likely cause, and requires several things which are not stated in the question to be true (mutiple files, the error reporting lines to be in short tags, "I see my raw php code" etc.). -1

Comment: The example from the question: `<?php echo explode('cms/', pageURL())[0]?>` As you can see, the open and close tags have been clearly demonstrated as being _normal, full_ PHP tags... NOT short tags.

Comment: @JMTyler but in that page if there would be code like <? ?> then it will not work this is the only reason.we doesn't know whole page. in the question user defined 2 lines only of that page not whole page.